# Frobenius method on $y''+x^2.y=0\; ; \; y(1)=0 \; ; \; y'(1)=1$ ($y$ roots)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, roots, frobenius-method

The differential problem is $$y''+x^2.y=0$$ $$y(1)=0\; ;\; y'(1)=1$$
I have to find a possible solution for this problem, show that $y(x)$ has another roots and find the next root for $x>1$.

Using the Frobenius method, I found that $$y(x)=\frac{1}{4}.\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n!.(4.n-1).(4.n-5).\cdots. 3}.a_0.x^{4.n}+a_0+\frac{1}{4}.\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n!.(4.n+1).(4.n-3).\cdots.5}.a_1.x^{4.n+1}+a_1$$

How can I discover the values of $a_0$ and $a_1$ by using the expressions $y(1)=0\; ;\; y'(1)=1$ ?

Comment: As you have conditions only at $x = 1$, set up your equations to get a Taylor series centered at $x = 1$...

Comment: By the Sturm-Picone comparison theorem, the next root is smaller than $1+\pi$.

Comment: @vonbrand How could I transform this into a Taylor series?

Comment: Consider the shifted equation $u''(t)+(1+t)^2u(t)=0$ with $u(0)=0$, $u'(0)=1$ and compute its power series solution as before. // Does "find the next root" mean via a numerical method with some control over the error?

Comment: @LutzLehmann The students are not mean to use any numerical method in this question, the question says that the next root can be an approximation.

Comment: How else do you propose to find roots of parabolic cylinder functions, as in the [solution formula per WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%27%27%28x%29%2Bx%5E2*y%28x%29%3D0%2C+y%281%29%3D0%2C+y%27%281%29%3D1)?